# How to resolve this microsoft visual studio has encountered and needs to close

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Hi all i am encountering this problem `microsoft visual studio has encountered a problem and needs to close` particularly when i am opening one solution.. There are several solutions but when particularly opening a particular solution i am getting this problem. Can any one tell how to resolve this..

I tried this by opening visual studio in command prompt but the issue still remains

`Devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`

Comment: Are there any logs in the event viewer or visual studio folder? Which SP version of VS 2008 are you running?

Comment: This is a bug in VS. It shouldn't crash. You might want to take this up with MS support.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue, but when attempting to open an SSIS package (.dtsx). It's strange b/c it's only happening with a particular package, while I'm able to open others fine. Any advice on how I can resolve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I get this error, I can fix it by deleting the **[.suo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx)** file associated with the solution. It will be recreated when you next open your solution.

---

**EDIT**

To iterate what sacredfaith said in the comments, whenever you delete anything it is **very prudent** to make a backup of the item before you delete it.

Comment: Exercise caution when attempting this (MAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR .suo FILE!), however, especially if you work in a collaborative environment (e.g. Team Foundation Server environment) as it may cause you to have to check out every conflicting change across everyone making changes to the solution. I was able to restore my .suo from the recycle bin, 3000+ files had conflicts (many were identical, but VS treated them as having been changed).

Comment: where the .suo file is located

Comment: @monicabubna Right click your solution in the solution explore, select `Open Folder In Windows Explorer` you will find the file there. Make sure you make a backup before deleting, expecially if you are using Team Foundation Server for source control per sacredfaith's comment.

Comment: by deleting the .suo file the error will be resolved their is any other solution is there to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Solution files are text-based and VS Project files are XML - you might want to try opening them in a text-editor and checking they have a valid syntax.

Other problems include path names that are too long (make sure the directory structure is not too deep) and also ensure the files are not read-only.

Have you tried cleaning (deleting) all the built and auto-generated files (ncb, suo, ilk, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try these option:

start -> run -> devenv /resetsettings (reset default settings)

start -> run -> devenv /ResetSkipPkgs (disable packages)

Comment: I'm also facing same issues . But i running ssis package in  production server. If i run in safe mode whether  it will restart visual studio alone or sever also.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried many things. But at last, after not finding any ways, I simply uninstalled it and then installed it again. And its up and running like before.