# MS Visual Studio 2008 crashes whenever I open designer view in Windows Form app

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Whenever I open any designer view of any form in my solution, my VS 2008 crashes. Every time. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940625/how-to-resolve-this-microsoft-visual-studio-has-encountered-and-needs-to-close) , but it doesn't work. What can I do to stop this problem.[image: Error message image]

Comment: have you tried installing service packs?

Comment: @patrickchoi: yes I had installed SP1

Comment: Any form design will do this? Does this happen with a brand new project and a brand new form? otherwise your forms have a common problem (like they all derive from another nasty one)