# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 IDE is not opening

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

When I am opening the IDE **Visual Studio 2010**, it's showing the error

> "Microsoft Visual Studio has encounter a problem and needs to close."
>
> If you had files open contained unsaved changes, these changes might
>   be lost.
>
> Check online for a solution and close the program
>
> Close the program
>
> Debug the program
>
> Details
>
> Problem signature:
>
> ```
>  Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3
>
>  Problem Signature 01:    devenv.exe
>
>  Problem Signature 02:    10.0.30319.1
>
>  Problem Signature 03:    4ba1fab3
>
>  Problem Signature 04:    Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common
>
>  Problem Signature 05:    10.0.0.0
>
>  Problem Signature 06:    5140b069
>
>  Problem Signature 07:    4b6
>
>  Problem Signature 08:    45
>
>  Problem Signature 09:    System.MissingMethodException
>
>  OS Version:  6.0.6002.2.2.0.272.7
>
>  Locale ID:   1033
> ```
>
> Additional information about the problem:   LCID: 1033
>
> Read our privacy statement:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=50163&clcid=0x0409

I'm using **Windows Server 2008 R2**.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940625/how-to-resolve-this-microsoft-visual-studio-has-encountered-and-needs-to-close

Comment: IF the above din work, then repair your VS ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your visual studio from command prompt with /safemode parameter.
Then disable every extension you've installed before, then re-run visual studio.

For example: 
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /safemode

It would be nice if you run you cmd as an admin.

Good luck

Comment: Thank you Yasser for you suggestion. Its working but for once, when I logging in again it's repeat the same error.

Comment: Could you please uninstall any visual studio extensions you've installed before, and tell me the results ? From Tools>Extensions Manager >> I hope this fix your problem.

Comment: I'm also facing same issues . But i running ssis package in  production server. If i run in safe mode whether  it will restart visual studio alone or sever also.

Comment: I am facing same issue. even in the /safemode IDE is not coming up. When I run devenv.exe it just flashes